# DRC tool for Gerber files

Tags: pcb, gerber, drc

Do you know any tools which perform design rule checking for Gerber files of PCB and are suitable for using in batch mode on a remote server? Something similar to what [BatchPCB](http://batchpcb.com) or [FreeDFM](https://www.my4pcb.com/net35/FreeDFMNet/FreeDFMHome.aspx) uses (I asked BatchPCB but they haven't answered yet.)

Comment: Have a look at ADIVA: http://www.adiva.com

Comment: I could not find anything different than the two websites mentioned, you may be more successful by combining open-source tools like kiCAD and making an open-sourced DRC website.  Here are some other ECAD tools, http://www.terrypin.dial.pipex.com/ECADList.html

Comment: Look at Numerical Innovations DFM Now!

Comment: @EE_socal might be a good idea to expand this recommendation into an answer

Comment: Typically DFM rules are dependent on the PCB manufacturer and not based strictly on IPC Specs.  It really depends on the type of PCB design you are creating. So the tool is ONLY as GOOD as the Rules which depends on DFT. DFC DFM and DRC

Comment: Mentor calls DRC or rather DFM =MRA ( Manufacturing Risk Assessment ) this may include dynamic rules the design can check in real time so the post-assessment list is reduced,  There are hundreds of rules that mostly relate to solderability, not just human errors. Solderability is the biggest risk in mass production with high volume effects on choice of methods of soldering (wave vs Reflow vs Force air reflow vs....) and each pad aperture and gap may be different. as well as orientation for solder flow.  Yields are dominated by Bad Design, then bad process then bad parts.

Answer (score 1):

DRC is a rules-based software that requires maintenance to latest IEC design specs. These change annually, so don't expect too much from a free DRC checker unless you are doing old technology.

Also beware that the requirements of pick and place, reflow/wave solder, and hand solder change all the rules.

You might be able to afford this:  http://wssi.com/gerbtool/

Comment: DRC is a function of most EDA software, so it's not a separate software like you suggest in your answer. Also, while it's wise to follow IEC or IPC standard evolution, you can use your own set of rules, depending on experience and agreements with the PCB shop.

Comment: Of course if the OP had such EDA tools, he wouldn't be asking. Also EDA tools must be updated at a cost to get updated DRC rules for newer parts. There are many independent examples, and if the OP had any EDA types ($) he would know and not ask, so stevenh's  assumption was incorrect.

Comment: @stevenvh Perhaps you do not know that DFX is an umbrella of wisdom of all those acronyms, DFC DFM, DFT, +DRC = DFX. Each vendor may change the u Bella size to suit their software as Mentor did in my example.Nothing I said is incorrect, nor have you supported your claim.Those that agree with you are inexperienced.

Answer (score -1):

1. Consult and obtain the latest [DRC guidlines from *IPC* http://landpatterns.ipc.org/default.asp
2. Use IPC design tools for special (e.g. RF ) *applications* www.ipc.org/ContentPage.aspx?Pageid=PCB-Tools-and-Calculators
3. Get a free Design review for DFM from a supplier such as *www.pentalogix.com/*
4. If you can not afford a $100K Mentor graphics seat communities.mentor.com/mgcx/community/pcb
5. get Eagle with DRC www2.ee.ic.ac.uk/t.clarke/eagle/Eagle_configuration.htm

I trust one of these suggestions is adequate for you.